# In Objective C UITableVIew how to retain scroll position after calling reload

Tags: ios, uitableview

In Objective C UITableVIew how to retain scroll position after calling reload

While selecting a cell I call reload function of the UITableView but after reload I want the scroll to maintain its position (i.e, Position where the cell was tapped)

Comment: When you select the cell is it taking you to another view?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:withRowAnimation`: instead of `reloadData`.

Comment: But Constraints provide lots of problem.. :(

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    [tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];
}
```

Also if you want to scroll to some particular position, you can use this.

```
  [tableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath:indexPath atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionNone animated:YES];
```

Comment: He is asking how to maintain the same position if reload happens. Not asking how to scroll to a particular position.

Comment: @LucasHuang he included both cases in his answer, shouldn't be down voted for that. He said _if you want to scroll._ this isn't that bad of answer, you both should elaborate more on `reloadRowsAtIndexPath:` or offer examples on how to maintain contentOffset. Should OP use begin/end updates, how does the OP reload _all_ the rows if their main intend is to reloadData [the whole table] etc etc

Comment: Thanks for you comment anyway. Just think that he did not answer what the OP exactly want. His answer is not wrong though.

Comment: But he wrote exactly what you wrote @LucasHuang ??

Comment: Then, what's the point to answer one more time. Anyway, we are both helpful though.

Answer (score 0):

Two lines and you get the desired result:

```
 NSArray *indexPaths = tableView.indexPathsForVisibleRows;
[tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:indexPathswithRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];'
```